# How to convert a JavaScript string[] to Windows.Foundation.Collection.IIterable<string>?

Tags: typescript, uwp, windows-runtime, c++-winrt, react-native-windows

I'm working on a React Native Windows project, and am using the projected findAllDevicesAsync() method in `Windows.Devices.Enumeration` namespace. An overload of the function accepts an IIterable as an additional property, which I want to provide.

I have an array of properties defined in TypeScript:

```
const propertyKeys: string[] = [
    HOSTNAME_PROPERTY,
    SERVICENAME_PROPERTY,
    INSTANCENAME_PROPERTY,
    IPADDRESS_PROPERTY,
    PORTNUMBER_PROPERTY,
    TEXTATTRIBUTES_PROPERTY
    ];
```

When I pass this to the projected `findAllAsync()` method, I get the following error:

```
Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IIterable<string>'.
Property 'first' is missing in type 'string[]' but required in type 'IIterable<string>'
```

[Docs for FindAllDevicesAPI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation.findallasync?view=winrt-22621#windows-devices-enumeration-deviceinformation-findallasync(system-string-windows-foundation-collections-iiterable((system-string))-windows-devices-enumeration-deviceinformationkind))

Comment: Why do you mark the project with C++/WinRT, you're using typescript right? Please provide a reproducible sample code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example